# Matrix equation $iA = AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, abelian-varieties

Let $A \in \mathrm{M}_{n, 2n}(\mathbb{C})$  be a matrix which rows are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Let
$$
B := \begin{pmatrix} A \\ \overline{A} \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} i 1_n & 0 \\ 0 & i 1_n  \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} A \\ \overline{A} \end{pmatrix},$$
where $\overline{A}$ is the complex conjugate of $A$. I want show that $i A = AB$. Does anybody know how to do this?

I know that $B = \begin{pmatrix} A \\\ \overline{A} \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} i A \\\ \overline{i A} \end{pmatrix}$, but I don´t know how to proceed.

Comment: Multiply on the left by $A$, and note that row $i$ of $A$ is the same as row $i$ of $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ \overline A \end{bmatrix} $, for $1\le i \le n$.

Comment: The bottom block of the one matrix should be $i\overline{A}$ instead of $\overline{iA}$, but it won't matter since it's multiplied by a block of zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} A \\\ \overline{A} \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} i A \\\ \overline{i A} \end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix} A \\\ \overline{A} \end{pmatrix} B = \begin{pmatrix} i A \\\ \overline{i A} \end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix} A B \\\ \overline{A} B \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} i A \\\ \overline{i A} \end{pmatrix}\\
$$

Reading the top $n$ lines shows $AB = iA$.